# Unix RedHat - Can't exclude "Permission denied" message on "find" command

Tags: unix, permissions, find, redhat

I'm working on RedHat unix server and I need to run a 'find' command to search some text files but ever 'find' return "Permission denied" for some directory.

**I searched on other similar posts here on stack overflow but no one of the given answers has resolved my issue.**

This is the command I run:

```
    find . -name "*file_name*20200310*"
```

An these are the option I tried without success:

```
    find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" -type f

    find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" 2>/dev/null

    find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" | grep -v "Permission denied"

    find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" -nowarn   # really, this option '-nowarn' is about
```

warning

I red the **find** manual (unix 'man') but didn't find a solution.

Please, anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Ale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … these are the option I tried without success:
>
> ```
> …
>     find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" | grep -v "Permission denied"
> …
> ```
>
> I'm on /usr/bin/csh

To make this work with `csh`, we have to use the pipe operator `|&` which redirects also `stderr`:

```
find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" |& grep -v "Permission denied"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution by entering into `ksh` shell and using `2>/dev/null` at the end of line.

Is not a real solution but now is the first thing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

> … these are the option I tried without success:
>
> ```
> …
>     find . -name "*file_name*20200310*" 2>/dev/null
> …
> ```
>
> I'm on /usr/bin/csh

The `2>` to redirect the standard error stream is not understood by `csh`.

To skip over the contents of unreadable directories, we can use the *test*

```
   -readable
          Matches  files  which  are  readable.   …
```

and the *action*

```
   -prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.  …
```

in connection:

```
find . \! -readable -prune , -name "*file_name*20200310*"
```

Comment: Thank you Armali but it doesn't give back the result expected.
With these options it list all the files present on FS other than mine + 'Permissione denied' messages.
It seems the option
`-name "file_name*20200310*"` there wasn't.
I tried to add a ` | grep "file_name*20200310*"` but it give back only the rows with **'Permission denied'** message.

Comment: @Alessandro Barca - Ah, I used a wrong _operator_, corrected.

Comment: I run new command        `find . \! -executable -prune , -name "*file_name*20200310*"`        but the message still printed on stdout; i put an example of the message:        
**find: `./aaa/bbb': Permission denied**

Comment: @Alessandro Barca - Could you post the output of `ls -ld aaa/bbb` (file for which error message is printed)? And are you sure _the message still printed on **stdout**_? It should be printed to **stderr**.

Comment: I can't publish the print-screen of my output but I can write trhe record printed on video:         `drwx--x--- 4 ownerusr groupusr 4096 May 23  2019 ./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/`.
           The `ownerusr` is **different** from the `user` i run the `find` command from.

Comment: @Alessandro Barca - Ah, I didn't test the case where `groupusr` is the same and there's execute, but not read permission for the group. As far as I see now, `readable` is appropriate, not `executable`.

Comment: ok, Thank you. Result doesn't change. I think that message is related to the shell in use. In facr, with KSH i can redirect stderror to `/dev/null` and it works fine.

Comment: @Alessandro Barca - Thanks for the info. Sadly I can't reproduce the behavior here (also using `csh`, which shouldn't matter as long as no redirection is used).